# PHP Preg expression to remove html tags and inner contents from string?

Tags: php, preg-replace, expression

quick question.

I'd like to remove the sup tag from the following string, and all content within it.

```
$string = "Priority Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> International";
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imagine something like this would work:

```
preg_replace("(<([a-z]+)>.*?</\\1>)is","",$input);
```

Comment: if the inner html contains HTML tags (such as an anchor <a href...>) this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace ("/<sup>(.*?)<\/sup>/i", "", $string);
```

You should know that (.*?) can't deal with \n or \r, so filter them first.

Comment: Not working, this is the output I'm getting: Priority Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> International

Comment: I run the code and it's working, don't know what's problem your side, you can put them into a single Php and try

Comment: If you're going to include the tag name, why not just do `$string = str_replace("<sup>&reg;</sup>","",$string)` or even `$string = substr($string,0,13).substr($string,29);` and claim it answers the question completely?

Comment: I guess, he just want to remove <sup> tag.