# How can i let preg_replace show the accents

Tags: php

I'm using this function to block some special characters.

```
function safeEscape($val) {
    $valEscape = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $val);
    $valSafe = mysql_real_escape_string($valEscape);
    return $valSafe;
}
```

But when i insert something with accents into my database, exemple:

Tést

preg_replace blocks the word.

how can i prevent that?

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: @user What's the idea behind "blocking some special characters" to begin with?!

Comment: my english sucks, but i want to block tags like <script> and ...

Comment: Start here: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10508826/790454

Comment: See this page it may help....


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508801/php-preg-expression-to-remove-html-tags-and-inner-contents-from-string/10508826#10508826

Answer (score 0):

Your code does actually work:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
function safeEscape($val) {
    $valEscape = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $val);
    $valSafe = mysql_real_escape_string($valEscape);
    return $valSafe;
}
echo safeEscape("Test");
echo safeEscape("Tést");
echo safeEscape("T£st");
```

**Output:**

```
TestTéstTst
```

So the problem is somewhere else. Perhaps you're using a mixture of text encodings somewhere?

But having said that, if you just want to sanitize user input to prevent cross-site scripting, then you may be going a bit too far. For HTML, it is sufficient to replace `<`, `>` and `&` with their escaped equivalents.

Also, the answer linked to by Feroz is not going to protect you from cross-site scripting:

```
preg_replace("(<([a-z]+)>.*?</\\1>)is","",$input);
```

For example, try passing this to your script: `<script >alert("XSS")</script>`